# user privileges to roles and features using rails and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec, roles, privileges

i am new about rails and respect, so i hope found the answer here,

i have some models here, and all of it have many to many relations

**user -- role_user -- role -- role_feature -- feature**

role_user and role_feature is the middle table to connect the many to many relations, I have completed all the controller crud and the model relations table, and also tested both of it with rspec and it is 100% coverage, so dont worry about it. and i haven't do anything about views, just model, controller and rspect.

Now I want to create privilege/permissions for each user in accessing existing features, so each user has a role and the role has many features,

in the file seeds.rb

```
RoleUser.where(role_id: 1, user_id:1).first_or_create;
Role.where(holding_company_id: 1, name: 'Area Index').first_or_create;
RoleFeature.where(role_id: 1, feature_id:1).first_or_create;
Feature.where(name: 'Area Index', key: 'area_index').first_or_create;
Feature.where(name: 'Area Create', key: 'area_create').first_or_create;
```

in the file area.rb (i take example area)

```
class AreasController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_access

  def index
    if params[:per_page].blank? && params[:page].blank?
      areas = Area.where(holding_company_id: current_holding_company.id)
    else
      areas = Area.where(holding_company_id: current_holding_company.id).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page])
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: areas.to_json, status: 200 }
    end
  end

  def create
  end

  def update
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
  end

  protected
    def check_access
        case params[:action]
          when 'index'
            unless current_user.roles.features.include? (area_index)
              render nothing: true, status: 200
            end 
        end    
    end

end
```

and the spec is

```
require 'spec_helper'  

describe AreasController, :type => :controller do

  before(:each) do
    @token = FactoryGirl.create(:token)
    @area = FactoryGirl.create(:area_1)
    FactoryGirl.create(:area_2)
    FactoryGirl.create(:area_3)
  end

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success for json without pagination" do
      get 'index', token: @token.token_string, format: :json
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body).count).to eq(3)
      expect(Area.count).to eq(3)
    end

     it "returns http success for json with pagination" do
      get 'index', token: @token.token_string, format: :json, page: 1, per_page: 2
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      expect(JSON.parse(response.body).count).to eq(2)
    end
  end

  describe "POST 'create'" do
  end

  describe "PUT 'update'" do
  end

  describe "GET 'show'" do
  end

  describe "DELETE 'destroy'" do
  end

end
```

and the problem is there is an error/failure while testing it with rspec, its said undefined method role, i try to fix it , i spent hours just for browse it on internet, but it's useless. so i hope this is the final chance for me, i need your help guys...

Comment: It might help to include the code from the spec in your question.

Comment: ok, i just add the spec file above